# Como descobrir em SQL qual é a chave primária da tabela?

Tags: sql, query, chave-primária, h2database

Estou aprendendo SQL, e esbarrei no seguinte problema:

Preciso saber qual das colunas é a chave primária da tabela.
Tem algum comando que posso usar no SELECT pra obter como retorno
essa informação?

Já vi o tópico:

[Como montar um select que traga informações de qual coluna é PK, qual não é, e qual é FK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69608/como-montar-um-select-que-traga-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-qual-coluna-%c3%a9-pk-qual-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-e-q)

Não ajudou em nada.

Comment: Qual SGBD esta a usar?

Comment: Olá. é o H2 Database Engine.

Comment: De uma olhada [link](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=information_schema&search=INFORMATION_SCHEMA#firstFound), acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: Pior que não encontrei nada nesse link também. Você sabe como isso é feito em algum outro SGBD?

Comment: Ler a tabela correta de Metadados (metadata) do BD em questão.